# IE6/7 Google Maps tile transparency - I can't see the map

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, opacity

I am currently building a site that utilises the Google Maps V3 API. It works as expected on Firefox/Chrome/Safari/Opera/IE8 - but in IE6 and 7 the map tiles are transparent. The overlay appears but the map tiles appear to be hidden. I say 'appear to be' because, if I drag the map quickly the tiles are there then they disappear - so it must be javascript hiding it?

Here's an image of the problem:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10007971/mm/mm_google_map_error.jpg

I am using opacity in my CSS which may be the root of the problem.

If code is needed I am happy to post it.

Thanks,

Ollie

Comment: Yes, please post your markup and code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - I will have to post links in seperate comments as I only joined the site a couple of weeks ago. I had to obfuscate some data but it shouldn't make any difference. Here's the PHP output: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10007971/mm/mm.html

Comment: Here's the default stylesheet: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10007971/mm/default.css

Comment: Here's the additional styls used by ie6/7: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10007971/mm/ie6.css

Comment: Why not just post a link to your site, so that we can introspect the code?

Comment: Because it's currently running on my local machine using Wamp. I've discovered that I've fallen victim to the IE6/7 'position:relative;' 'bug'. I'm gonna mess around with it now and I'm sure I'll get it sorted. Thanks for everyone who's had a look at it for me already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just had a similar problem. I was setting the opacity of one of the map's parent elements using jquery. Obviously in IE6 & 7 this uses `filter: alpha(opacity=X)` property. Removing this seemed to resolve the issue with the invisible map tiles.

Hope this helps.